# Adding text, excel table and the default signature to outlook

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with a button, which when the user click on it, should be opened an outlook mailbox with specific excel table, several text lines at the beginning of the mail body (before the table), and my default signature (as defined in outlook) should be there too.
When i run my code, only the excel table is appaering on the mail body (the required text before the table and the signature is missing).

Please your help, thanks a lot

here is my code:

```
Sub SendCA_list()

Dim oApp As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim oMail As Object
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'select the table
Range("Table4[[#Headers],[Department]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-129
Selection.Copy


With oMail



.Body = "Hi All," & vbNewLine & "Enclosed below open A/Is list from last ISO Internal Audit. Please review and perform the required corrective actions." & vbNewLine & "Please update status and details in the audit report until next week."

Dim wordDoc As Object
Set wordDoc = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
wordDoc.Range.Paste

.Display

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i used `.body` instead of `.htmlbody`.

Here is the correct code:

```
Sub SendCA_list()

Dim oApp As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim oMail As Object
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Range("Table4[[#Headers],[Department]]").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-129
Selection.Copy 'select and copy the required table

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'range of selected table

With oMail

.HtmlBody = "Hi All," & "<br>" & "Enclosed below open A/Is list from last ISO Internal Audit. Please review and perform the required corrective actions." & "<br>" & "Please update status and details in the audit report until next week." 

Dim wordDoc As Object
Set wordDoc = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

oMail.HtmlBody = .HtmlBody & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) 'this is a function which paste the selected range to outlook mail in html format

.Display
End With

End Sub
```

Function for insert the range from excel to html body mail:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

With TempWB.Sheets(1)
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, , False, False
   .Cells(1).Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   On Error Resume Next
   .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
   .DrawingObjects.Delete
   On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
 End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML1 = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML1 = Replace(RangetoHTML1, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

u can try like this.

it checks where the inserted text stops and paste the data after.

```
With OutMail

 .Body = "Hi All," & vbNewLine & "Enclosed below open A/Is list from last ISO Internal Audit. Please review and perform the required corrective actions." & vbNewLine & "Please update status and details in the audit report until next week." & vbCrLf

 Dim wordDoc As Object
 Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

 wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
 wordDoc.Application.Selection.End = Len(.Body)

 wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paste

 Display

End With
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, i would like to know about this option

Comment: it's stuck on the line  'wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)' the error massage is: "run time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: sorry, ive forget to put the "End With" after that. i've update my answer

Comment: now it stuck on the line  <wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paste> error massage is: run time error 4605: 'this method or property is not available because this document is locked for eddidting" (my excel file isn't protected)

Comment: try to copy a range of data instead using Range("Table4[[#Headers],[Department]]").Select, like range("A1:B10").Select  just to debug